# How to create login client's account with Twitter?

Tags: python, authentication, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

I've created a web application, Now i want to put `login authentication` using twitter account.

As Stackoverflow include `Gmail`, `Facebook` to login into stackoverflow. Similarly i want to make the same thing with my application.

I'm bit confused here, Here is example i found. Please see [this](http://demos.9lessons.info/twitter-facebook2/login.php).

I found it into URL bar it generates this:

```
https://twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token=VOU5SAAAAAAAASO2AAABUBx3tgE
```

But i'm finding difficulties to generate my own's application `oauth_token`. Can you please help me? How to generate it? I googled and searched into twitter everywhere. But none of things worked for me. :(

Please Help me.. **HELP WOULD BE APPRECIATED!!**

Comment: What language did u use to build your app?